# Phone gap with native code

Tags: cordova, cross-platform

I am starting out with PhoneGap and have built a simple application completely in Phonegap - HTML5 and JS.

My question is -
**1.** Can I combine two "sub-applications" - one written in PhoneGap and other written in native and combine it in 1 application.
**2.** Is it possible to say that 1 screen in the app is done using native code (the XML that we write in Android) and the other screens in PhoneGap (HTML5)?

How can I do these?

Answer (score 0):

The current version on Cordova (PhoneGap) only supports this for iOS. There will be support to do this on Android but I don't know what version it will ship in.

***EDIT***

iOS documentation - https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/How%20to%20Use%20Cordova%20as%20a%20Component.md

Android - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-callback-commits/201205.mbox/%3C20120516183628.9B15F163EE@tyr.zones.apache.org%3E

This mailing list post talks about the capability for Android from v1.8 which is now released.

Comment: The Android support slipped into 1.9 but has been merged into the main branch so it is a lock for our 1.9 release.